# Entity Framework - best practice to get count

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a Customer table and another Orders table. Each Customer can have many orders (One to many relationship).

I want to get a Customer object and from it get how many orders he has (the actual order data is not relevant at this point). So as I see it I have 2 options:

1. create a view with another OrdersCount field - and that will be another object in my system.
2. in my app, when I need the count get the Customer.Orders.Count - but for my understanding that will cause an extra query to run and pull all the orders from the database to that collection.

Is there a correct way to do such thing?

Thanks

Comment: "for my understanding that will cause an extra query to run and pull all the orders from the database to that collection." That would be a rather silly thing of the EF to do, wouldn't it? Try it out: you should see a query that pulls count from the database without "materializing" the order collection.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Are you sure about that? Sure, `context.Orders.Count()` would behave like you described, but `context.Customers.Single().Order` will likely have type `ICollection<Order>` (or a concrete implementation of that interface), so how could you call `Queryable.Count` if you don't have an `IQueryable` instance?

Comment: `Customers.Select(x => {Count=x.Orders.Count, Name = x.CustomerName})` will make exactly _zero_ queries. Calling `.ToList` on it or enumerating it will make exactly one database query. As long as you're running code inside an IQueryable context in EntityFramework it'll only run a single query when you enumerate its results (that doesn't mean it'll be fast though). Watch out for `ToList`ing too early and ending up with the "Select N+1" problem.

Comment: @hvd One would need to be smart to stay within `IQueryable` context, so rather than calling `context.Customers.Where(c => c.Id==custId).Single().Orders.Count()` one should call `context.Orders.Count(o => o.customerId == custId)` or something to that effect (EDIT: e.g. what you described in your answer :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight And be careful not to put that in a property getter. It may be called more often than you might expect.

Answer (score 1):

You do need a new type, but you don't need to recreate all relevant properties.

```
from c in context.Customers
// where ...
select new {
  Customer = c,
  OrderCount = c.Orders.Count()
}
```

Update code that looks for e.g. the `Name` property of an item in the result, to look for `Customer.Name`.